# How to get list data value Ionic 2 From JSON?

Tags: json, typescript, charts, ionic2, ionic3

This my JSON data :

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "label": "saw",
    "total": "100"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "label": "saw1",
    "total": "300"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "label": "saw2",
    "total": "400"
  }
]
```

This my Typescript

```
this.http.get('http://www/upnionic/chart.php')
  .map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
    this.qwerty = data; this.qwerty.forEach(element => {
        let product = element.total;
        this.pieChartData = product; 
        console.log(product);
    }); 
});
```

How to get view data Json like this in HTML ionic 2 ?

```
["100","300","400"]
```

Comment: `var totalArray = data.map((item) => item.total);`

Comment: This Worked !!!!, Thanks a Lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PFB the sample code to extract value from array and put it into another array

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  jsonData : any;
  val : any=[];
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.jsonData=[{"id":1,"label":"saw","total":"100"},{"id":2,"label":"saw1","total":"300"},{"id":3,"label":"saw2","total":"400"}];
    this.jsonData.map((item)=>{
      this.val.push(item.total);
    });
    alert(this.val);
  }

}
```